# How to stop iteration when all values in Numpy array rises above threshold which is integar?

Tags: numpy

Im stuck with Numpy  exercise that say:

Use mask to multiply  all values belowe 100 in folowing list by 2:

a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])

Repeat this until all values are above 100.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])

cutoff = 100

for i in range (10):
    a[a < cutoff] *= 2
    print (a)
    if a.all() > cutoff:
        break
```

I dont know how to stop iteration when all values in array rise above cutoff value? i think numpy.all() dont works with intger?!

Comment: Apply `all` to the `a>cutoff` boolean array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) docs:

> Test whether all array elements along a given axis evaluate to True.

That is, `numpy.all` returns a single `bool`, so in `a.all() > cutoff` you are really doing `True > cutoff` or `False > cutoff`, which evaluate to `1 > cutoff` and `0 > cutoff`, so it's always `False` for `cutoff = 100`.

You should change the `if` condition to get just the elements from `a` that are bigger than `cutoff` and execute `all` on those:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])

cutoff = 100

for i in range (10):
    a[a < cutoff] *= 2

    print(a)

    if (a  > cutoff).all(): // HERE
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while not (a < 100).all():
    a[a < 100] *= 2
```